# WordPress free version - theme editor is missing

Tags: wordpress

I'm going crazy with this one, I've tried all possible outcomes, but I can't access the theme editor nor the content.php or any kind of configurable code for that matter. The `theme editor` section under appearance is missing, if I try to access it through the URL [http://www.nameofsite.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php] I get:

> Lost?
> Our server sentries tell us you probably shouldn’t be here. Maybe you’re lost?

All other solutions to this problem, including the other question here in SO refer to either a plugin or modifying the `wp-config.php` which I can't access also because I'm not hosting the site. Yes I'm using the WordPress free web app and although that may be it I would like some confirmation because no site on the internet mentions if that is the case, I'm just assuming here, so is it because I'm using the free version, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.
Only if you have Premium plan and above then you'll have access to `Theme Editor`:

[image: Wordpress.com Pricing Plans]

As for editing the `wp-config.php` file, you'll need the Business Plan and above:

[image]

Full pricing plan chart: https://wordpress.com/pricing/

Comment: well thank you, I know this is a silly question but rather ask it since I literally couldn't find anything on it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it definetly is because you are using the free WordPress.com version.
You can read it [here](https://wordpress.com/forums/topic/cant-find-theme-editor/) in the last answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out before, you need at least a Business plan in WordPress.com to be able to edit the theme and the `wp-config.php` file.

But maybe what you're trying to change does not need it. What do you want to change from your theme? it may be possible to do it using [the customizer](https://wordpress.com/support/customizer/)